# Error in BOWImgDescriptorExtractor of opencv for android because it does not have any parameter(extractor,matcher) in constructor.

Tags: opencv, image-processing, sift, android

I was trying to implement sift with BOW technique using a tutorial in which BOWImgDescriptorExtractor(opencv C++) was having 2 parameter (extractor,matcher) but I came to know that BOWImgDescriptorExtractor in opencv(3.2.0) for android does not have any parameter in its constructor. I want to know how to initialize BOWImgDescriptorExtractor in opencv(3.2.0) for android.